# How to measure coordination from a network?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The network is an undirected graph where each node represents a person and any link between people represents mutual collaboration in some task. How can I get evidence of coordination behavior from the graph through network analysis or graph theory?

I'll really appreaciate any hint of information you can give on this topic.

Comment: Is your question intended to make use of the _Mathematica_ software, or are you more interested in the general mathematical approach instead? If it's the latter, you should probably ask on math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm interested in both approaches because all the network analysis in which I'm working is utilizing Mathematica Software. So, I will better ask this question on math.stackexchange.com. Thank you again.

Comment: If you are interested in using _Mathematica_ to solve this problem, it would help us greatly in helping you if you could briefly outline the problem you are trying to solve, and provide any code which you have tried to use to solve this problem.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SocialNetworks.html).

Comment: This question is neither about Mathematica nor about mathematics, so I do not think it fits either here or on Math.SE.  The first step is explaining what you mean by the very vague term "coordination behaviour".  Then you should think about what reasonable ways are there to formalize/quantify this subjective concept.  Only after that does it become a suitable question here (how to implement that formalization).

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [community detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_structure), but it's up to you to decide what makes sense for your problem

Comment: Hi @Szabolcs thanks for your answer. Coordination could be formalize as the organization of the different elements of the complex network so as to enable them to work together effectively. I agree with you now that the problem is the implementation of that formalization. Although, I'm going to revise that of community detection you mentioned.

Answer (score 9):

Generally read this: [Social Network Analysis](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SocialNetworks.html) There are 2 things to be aware:

- Different ways of defining "coordination"
- Different methods of detecting "coordination"

Some things could be quite simple, for example `FindClique` can be a great tool. Find a largest immediate family in a network consisting of the closest relatives:

```
SetProperty[ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "FamilyGathering"}],PlotTheme -> "Web"];
HighlightGraph[%, Subgraph[% , FindClique[%]]]
```

[image]

Other things require mining and tricks. Here is an example I developed to showcase data mining with graph & network (GN) methods. It is quite basic but effective, because we can verify its prediction. The idea was to take a group of famous modern actors about whom we do know some types of close interactions, in this case obviously common films work and dating/marriage. The goal to see those interactions in data w/ GN tools. *Data are based on the fact that famous people are public figures, and if there is a relationships between any 2 their Wikipedia pages will get correlated web traffic.* **I assume that relationships between these actors are very well known to public and do not need my explanation**.

Define a list of actors:

```
actors={"Brad Pitt","Angelina Jolie","Nicole Kidman",
"Jennifer Aniston","Katie Holmes","Tom Cruise",
"Blake Lively","Ryan Reynolds","Bradley Cooper",
"Gwyneth Paltrow","Robert Downey Jr","Daniel Craig",
"Rachel Weisz","Scarlett Johansson","Jennifer Lawrence"};
```

Here is a function to call Wolfram|Alpha data on daily hits of English Wikipedia page of a term:

```
waw[a_]:=TimeSeries[WolframAlpha[a,
{{"PopularityPod:WikipediaStatsData",1},"TimeSeriesData"}]]
```

Let's apply the call to all actors:

```
actorsTS=ParallelMap[waw,actors];
```

We can now demonstrate that these data are more correlated for some actors, like Jolie & Pitt, who are married.

```
DateListPlot[actorsTS[[;;3]],AspectRatio->1/5,ImageSize->Full,PlotTheme->"Detailed",
PlotRange->All,ScalingFunctions->"Log",PlotLegends->Placed[actors[[;;3]],Above]]
```

[image]

We can now build correlation matrix for our graph by computing each mutual relationship via Pearson's correlation coefficient:

```
corr=N[Outer[Correlation,actorsTS,actorsTS]];
```

Depicted best w/ heatmap:

```
MatrixPlot[corr,ColorFunction->"Rainbow",FrameTicks->{{#,#}&
[Transpose[{Range[Length[#]],#}&@actors]],{#,#}&
[Transpose[{Range[Length[#]],Rotate[#,Pi/2]&/@#}&@actors]]},
PlotLegends->Automatic,Mesh->All,MeshStyle->Directive[Opacity[.2],Dashed]]
```

[image]

Then compute weighted adjacency matrix and remove diagonal elements

```
am=ReplacePart[corr,{i_,i_}-> ∞];
```

Compute size of vertices based on total page hits:

```
vs=Rescale[Total/@actorsTS]//N;
```

Compute complete weighted graph all all mutual relationships:

```
g=WeightedAdjacencyGraph[actors,am,VertexLabels->
Placed["Name",Below],VertexSize->Thread[actors->vs]]
```

[image]

As graph is weighted we can use some community methods to find clustering:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[g,FindGraphCommunities[g,Method->"Modularity"],CommunityRegionStyle->
Directive[Opacity[.2],Gray],CommunityBoundaryStyle->Directive[Orange,Dashed]]
```

[image]

This already picked up on some common films (Hint: Marvel) and dating patterns. So I exposed `Method` in `FindGraphCommunities` for you to think about. Instead of playing with that we can take different route. Pearson's correlation coefficient is considered strong when is above $.4$. We could remove all edges weighted below considering them as noisy contribution to data. But I prefer to go even further - squeezing cut ofparameter to 1/2 - about percolation threshold - where graph just becomes connected. This is a sort of middle ground between completely connected and completely disconnected graph, and I think it reflects upon our graph structure.

```
am=ReplacePart[corr,{i_,i_}->∞]/.x_/;x<.5->∞;
g=WeightedAdjacencyGraph[actors,am,VertexLabels->Placed["Name",Below],
VertexSize->Thread[actors->vs],GraphLayout->"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"]
```

[image]

I also will use other approach - `FindGraphPartition` - that is handy when I know for how many communities I look for - here I estimate from intent to detect some "love-triangles"

```
CommunityGraphPlot[g,FindGraphPartition[g,5],CommunityRegionStyle->GrayLevel[.9],
CommunityBoundaryStyle->Directive[Orange,Dashed],Method->"Hierarchical"]
```

[image]

And now we did get a lot of things right - at least according to gossips ;-)